# 30's story about space war: Earth ship destroys enemy planet with weapon, only to return to find Earth destroyed by the enemy with the same weapon

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, space, weapon, warfare

Looking for 1930's short story about space war where Earth ship destroys enemy planet, only to return to find Earth destroyed by the enemy with the same weapon. The gist of the story was the debate on the Earth ship about the morality/ethics of using the weapon at all. I recall that the ship had to make jumps that took some time (basically allowed the discussion to unfold on the jump to the enemy system, and the jump back to Earth after deciding to launch the weapon).  I'd like to use it for a game engine cinematic plot.

Comment: Did you read it in a magazine, in a hardcover or paperback anthology, or online? What kind of weapon were they using to destroy planets? Was the enemy planet in our solar system or was it a planet of another star? What were they fighting over and who started it? Were the aliens humanoids, octopoids, plant-men, or machines?

Comment: Was there a twist ending (our fleet accidentally destroyed the Earth, not realising that it was the Earth)?

Comment: There's a similar one, where a ship activates an experimental faster than light ship from Earth/Sol to I think Sirius. Only for Sirius to go nova. And while they are discussing the possibility that the ftl drive caused the explosion and if it did, they can't go back to earth without destroying it, it dawns on them "what if it happens at the starting point too".

Comment: @cde, that one is Randall Garrett's "Time Fuze".  I flashed on that one too.

Comment: I'm thinking of Fredric Brown's "*Vengeance Fleet*" : Earth and Mars are about to go to war when an enemy space fleet suddenly appears and destroys the colonies on Venus. Mars and Earth instantly reach a truce and turn their guns on the enemy fleet which is destroyed without offering any defence. 
They determine the direction where the enemy came from and build a "vengeance fleet". They warp in and destroy the first planet they see, then realise that they've traveled back in time.